# How to store an array of generic elements in C++?

Tags: c++, hashtable, void

I'm trying to construct a Hashtable in C++ of fixed size; the table should be able to take data of any type, so I'm using templates to accomplish this. I'm attempting to use a void pointer array to hold my linked lists but I'm having an incredibly hard time making it work.

Node struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
   std::string key;
   T val;
   Node<T> next;
}
```

Class:

```
class HashTable {
private:
  int size;
  int elements;
  void **table;

public:
  HashTable(int size) {
    this->size = size;
    elements = 0;

    table = new void*[size];

    //initialize table
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      table[i] = NULL;
    }
  }

   ~HashTable() {
      delete [] table;
   }

 template <typename T>
   bool set(string key, T val) {
     std::tr1::hash<std::string> hash_function;
     std::size_t hash_value = hash_function(key);

     int idx = hash_value % size;

     if(table[idx] == NULL) {
       //newly created bucket, increment elements variable to signify bucket use
       elements++;

       Node<T> node;
       node.key = key;
       node.val = val;
       node.next = NULL;

       table[idx] = &node;

       cout << "Node: " << node.key << ", " << *node.val << endl; 

       //first error
       cout << "Table: " << table[idx].key << endl; 

       //second error
       cout << "Table: " << (Node<T>)table[idx].key << endl;

       //third error
       cout << "Table: " << static_cast<Node<T>>(table[idx]).key << endl;

     } else {

     }
  }

 //other methods
```

I get a lot of different errors depending on what I try...

1. `error: request for member 'key' in '((HashTable*)this)->HashTable::table[idx]', which is of non-class type 'void*'`
2. Same error as the first.
3. This line just gives me a whole wall of terrible error messages.

I have no idea how to make what I want work right now. What type of pointer should I make instead of void?

Comment: Why dont you make your HashTable a template?

Comment: You may look at `boost::any`.

Comment: Look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: Starting with templates and c++, and then immediately going to void * and and numerous casts is a bad idea. Why aren't you using std::vector<T> for your buckets?

Comment: The problem asks me to use primitive types only - so I can't use vector unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is a `void**`, so `table[idx]` is a `void*`. You solution should be something like:

```
((Node<T>*)table[idx])->key
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what it was! It works now. I can get the values I'm looking for with:

```((Node<T>*)table[idx])->key```
and
```*((Node<T>*)table[idx])->val```